# Terminal does not open under dwm -- is there an error log file?

Tags: arch-linux, dwm, urxvt

I am running DWM under Arch Linux in combination with the urxvt terminal. I have a urxvt daemon running but when I press the key combination for opening a terminal window, nothing happens.

Is there an error log file for DWM?

Any suggestions what I can do to find out why no terminal is opening?

Thanks!

Edit: My config.c file:

```
/* appearance */
static const char font[]            = "-*-terminus-medium-r-normal-*- 12-*-*-*-*-*-*-*";
static const char normbordercolor[] = "#000000";
static const char normbgcolor[]     = "#3f3f3f";
static const char normfgcolor[]     = "#dfaf8f";
static const char selbordercolor[]  = "#cc0000";
static const char selbgcolor[]      = "#2b2b2b";
static const char selfgcolor[]      = "#f0dfaf";
static const unsigned int borderpx  = 1;        /* border pixel of windows */
static const unsigned int snap      = 0;       /* snap pixel */
static const Bool showbar           = True;     /* False means no bar */
static const Bool topbar            = True;     /* False means bottom bar */

/* tagging */
static const char *tags[] = { "term", "work", "www", "mail"};

static const Rule rules[] = {
/* class      instance    title       tags mask     isfloating   monitor */
{ "Gimp",     NULL,       NULL,       0,            True,        -1 },
{ "Firefox",  NULL,       NULL,       1 << 8,       False,       -1 },
};

/* layout(s) */
static const float mfact      = 0.55; /* factor of master area size  [0.05..0.95] */
static const int nmaster      = 1;    /* number of clients in master area */
static const Bool resizehints = False; /* True means respect size hints in  tiled resizals */

static const Layout layouts[] = {
/* symbol     arrange function */
{ "[]=",      tile },    /* first entry is default */
{ "><>",      NULL },    /* no layout function means floating behavior */
{ "[M]",      monocle },
};

/* key definitions */
#define MODKEY Mod4Mask
#define TAGKEYS(KEY,TAG) \
{ MODKEY,                       KEY,      view,           {.ui = 1 << TAG}  }, \
{ MODKEY|ControlMask,           KEY,      toggleview,     {.ui = 1 << TAG} }, \
{ MODKEY|ShiftMask,             KEY,      tag,            {.ui = 1 << TAG} }, \
{ MODKEY|ControlMask|ShiftMask, KEY,      toggletag,      {.ui = 1 << TAG} },

/* helper for spawning shell commands in the pre dwm-5.0 fashion */
#define SHCMD(cmd) { .v = (const char*[]){ "/bin/sh", "-c", cmd, NULL } }

/* commands */
static const char *dmenucmd[] = { "dmenu_run", "-fn", font, "-nb", normbgcolor, "-nf", normfgcolor, "-sb", selbgcolor, "-sf", selfgcolor, NULL };
static const char *termcmd[]  = { "urxvtc", NULL };

static Key keys[] = {
/* modifier                     key        function        argument */
{ MODKEY,                       XK_p,      spawn,          {.v = dmenucmd } },
{ MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_Return, spawn,          {.v = termcmd } },
{ MODKEY,                       XK_b,      togglebar,      {0} },
{ MODKEY,                       XK_j,      focusstack,     {.i = +1 } },
{ MODKEY,                       XK_k,      focusstack,     {.i = -1 } },
{ MODKEY,                       XK_i,      incnmaster,     {.i = +1 } },
{ MODKEY,                       XK_d,      incnmaster,     {.i = -1 } },
{ MODKEY,                       XK_h,      setmfact,       {.f = -0.05} },
{ MODKEY,                       XK_l,      setmfact,       {.f = +0.05} },
{ MODKEY,                       XK_Return, zoom,           {0} },
{ MODKEY,                       XK_Tab,    view,           {0} },
{ MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_c,      killclient,     {0} },
{ MODKEY,                       XK_t,      setlayout,      {.v = &layouts[0]} },
{ MODKEY,                       XK_f,      setlayout,      {.v = &layouts[1]} },
{ MODKEY,                       XK_m,      setlayout,      {.v = &layouts[2]} },
{ MODKEY,                       XK_space,  setlayout,      {0} },
{ MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_space,  togglefloating, {0} },
{ MODKEY,                       XK_0,      view,           {.ui = ~0 } },
{ MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_0,      tag,            {.ui = ~0 } },
{ MODKEY,                       XK_comma,  focusmon,       {.i = -1 } },
{ MODKEY,                       XK_period, focusmon,       {.i = +1 } },
{ MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_comma,  tagmon,         {.i = -1 } },
{ MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_period, tagmon,         {.i = +1 } },
TAGKEYS(                        XK_1,                      0)
TAGKEYS(                        XK_2,                      1)
TAGKEYS(                        XK_3,                      2)
TAGKEYS(                        XK_4,                      3)
TAGKEYS(                        XK_5,                      4)
TAGKEYS(                        XK_6,                      5)
TAGKEYS(                        XK_7,                      6)
TAGKEYS(                        XK_8,                      7)
TAGKEYS(                        XK_9,                      8)
{ MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_q,      quit,           {0} },
};

/* button definitions */
/* click can be ClkLtSymbol, ClkStatusText, ClkWinTitle, ClkClientWin, or ClkRootWin */
static Button buttons[] = {
/* click                event mask      button          function        argument */
{ ClkLtSymbol,          0,              Button1,        setlayout,      {0} },
{ ClkLtSymbol,          0,              Button3,        setlayout,      {.v = &layouts[2]} },
{ ClkWinTitle,          0,              Button2,        zoom,           {0} },
{ ClkStatusText,        0,              Button2,        spawn,          {.v = termcmd } },
{ ClkClientWin,         MODKEY,         Button1,        movemouse,      {0} },
{ ClkClientWin,         MODKEY,         Button2,        togglefloating, {0} },
{ ClkClientWin,         MODKEY,         Button3,        resizemouse,    {0} },
{ ClkTagBar,            0,              Button1,        view,           {0} },
{ ClkTagBar,            0,              Button3,        toggleview,     {0} },
{ ClkTagBar,            MODKEY,         Button1,        tag,            {0} },
{ ClkTagBar,            MODKEY,         Button3,        toggletag,      {0} },
};
```

Comment: You can start `dwm` and log to an error file (`dwm 2> ~/dwm.log`). Please post your `config.h`.

Comment: Your `config.h` looks good. What keys are you pressing to launch the term? How are you starting `urxvtd`?

Comment: How do you start your X? If with any *dm see its log. If with startx check your tty's screen. But you can do as jasonwryan said.

Comment: I don't know about `dwm` specifically but the default stderr log file for any program running in an X11 session that does not somehow or other redirect its stderr is `~/.xsession-errors`.

Comment: It seems that you've changed the `ModKey` to be `super` so just to confirm, are you using `super + shift + return` key combination? Does it work if you set your terminal emulator to something else like `st`, `gnome-terminal`...? If it does then can you check if you have urxvtc installed. Also, can you try to run it via dmenu_run?
ie. by `super + p` key combination and then selecting your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

can you run urxvtc as mentionned in the line

```
/* com/* commands */
static const char *dmenucmd[] = { "dmenu_run", "-fn", font, "-nb", normbgcolor, "-nf", normfgcolor, "-sb", selbgcolor, "-sf", selfgcolor, NULL };
static const char *termcmd[]  = { "urxvtc", NULL };mands */
```

otherwise use another terminal

Answer (score 0):

You are executing as `termcmd` the `urxvtc` command:

```
static const char *termcmd[]  = { "urxvtc", NULL };
```

Note that this is the command for `urxvt` daemon control, therefore, the `urxvtd` daemon must first be running. Do you have the `urxvtd` command in your `.xinitrc` (or similar)?

For clarity:

- [`urxvt`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/urxvt.1) - `urxvt` terminal emulator.
- [`urxvtd`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/urxvtd.1) - `urxvt` terminal daemon.
- [`urxvtc`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/urxvtc.1) - control the `urxvtd` daemon.

Clarifying the question even more, in order to debug this call I consider that your best option is:

1. Execute with `dmenu` the command `urxvt`. If this step has gone well, you will have a terminal emulator open, and the `urxvt` emulator will work correctly without being demonized, so the problem is in the daemon or the daemon control and not in `urxvt`.
2. In that opened terminal, type `urxvtc`. If `urxvt` is correctly demonized, another terminal emulator should be opened, if it is not, it will throw an error like:

```
Unable to connect to the rxvt-unicode daemon: Connection refused
```

3. If there is an error, type `urxvtd &` and repeat step 2 again.
4. So, try the <kbd>Mod4</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> key shortcut to check that the `urxvtc` execution is correct with respect to the daemon, as specified in:

```
{ MODKEY|ShiftMask, XK_Return, spawn, {.v = termcmd } },
```

However, if all this seems complicated to you and you don't mind using demonization in `urxvt`, you can simplify the whole process and add the simple `urxvt` command instead of the daemon control, that is:

```
static const char *termcmd[]  = { "urxvt", NULL };
```